# Show Div if any Selected options in Multi Select equal or are more than custom Data Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, multi-select, custom-data-attribute

I have a script that shows a Div (incorporating a checkbox) that shows if a data-attribute select dropdown selection is more than 18 (for age verification for that option). The problem is if you select an option that does not have the data attribute 'data-age' of more or equal to 18 the div hides. I need it to show if 'any' of the multi-select options match the age criteria >=18. The code also needs to toggle the hidden checkbox as 'required' depending on whether a matching option is selected so that the form can submit if the div is hidden and ensure it's ticked for age verification confirmation if it is visible.

Current Code

```
<form>
<select multiple="" data-name="My Dropdown" name="My Dropdown" id="myDropdown">
<option value="">Select as many as you like...</option>
<option value="Option 1" data-age="">Option 1</option>
<option value="Option 2" data-age="18">Option 2</option>
<option value="Option 3" data-age="">Option 3</option>
<option value="Option 4" data-age="">Option 4</option>
<option value="Option 5" data-age="18">Option 5</option>
</select>

<div id="age-block">
<label>Age Verification</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="age-check" name="Age-Check" data-name="Age Check">
<span>I confirm that I am 18 and over for <span class="matches">Output Values matching age criteria</span></span></label>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" data-wait="Please wait...">
</form>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myDropdown").change(function() {
        var age = $("#myDropdown option:selected");
            //if ($("#myDropdown option:selected").data('age') >= '18') {
      if ($(age).data('age') >= '18') {
          $("#age-block").css('display', 'block');
          $("#age-check").attr("required", true);
           }
     else{
          $("#age-block").css('display', 'none');
            $("#age-check").attr("required", false);
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

All input is appreciated.

Thanks

Glennyboy

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant HTML. Also, is there some reason you need JQuery and data- attributes for this? Such a task is trivial, even with vanilla JS.

Comment: Don't use strings to compare numerics:  eg `'2' > '18'`

Comment: @ScottMarcus No it doesn't have to be jQuery. The HTML is just a drop down with data attribute (it's an attribute as the values are taken and the content is added dynamically via a CMS field) and a div containing the checkbox. I'll add it in when I come back online.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you are using the `option value` attributes properly. There is no need for `data-` attributes here. Just have the `option value` store the data that each option represents.

Comment: Those values are collected by the form entries and are used.